# Simple login/auth that works out of the box?

Tags: java, seam

I would like to setup a simple loginpage for my webapp.
As the app is not very crucial, a simple login would be sufficient.

The user should see and access some pages only if he is logged in.

Is there a simple thing with Seam 3, or plain JSF 2 likewise?
Preferable without XML.

tyvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with Seam 3, but it sure looks like you should be using [Seam Security](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule) ([docs](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/pt04.html)).